How to apply external spatial force to the end of a robot arm using drake?
I have added a kuka robot arm in the scene graph, and I can control the robot arm by typing desired position in the terminal. But I'm trying to apply force to the robot arm so it can move with my "hand", the same as free-drag function that every robot arm has. What is the correct way of doing this? Thanks in advance!
I tried to use get_applied_spatial_force_input_port() function in the multibody plant class, but I'm not sure how to construct the input spatial force.
